# How do I fix the "Call to a member function update() on null" error?

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to pull input data from the form into the database to run an update operation. However, their is an error that points directly to the line "$obj->update(request()->all());". The error is "Call to a member function update() on null". I am not too sure what this error means, but I think it means that request()->all() is null. What I want the output to be is after updating the user input to the database, the user will be redirected to the pageManagement.blade.php, through return redirect('/p'); However the current output is just an error message, stating "Call to a member function update() on null".

```
public function update($URI)
{
    $data = request()->validate([
        'title' => 'required',
        'URI' => 'required|min:5|max:10',
        'pageContent' => 'required'
    ]);
    $obj = \App\Page::find($URI);
    $obj->update(request()->all());
    return redirect('/p');
}
```

This is my model Page.php.

```
class Page extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['title', 'URI', 'pageContent'];
}
```

This is my route in web.php.

```
Route::patch('/page/{URI}','PageController@update');
```

This is my form for the user to enter the input data.

```
<form action="/page/{{ $pageContent->URI }}" method="post">
@csrf
@method('PATCH')
  <label for="title">Title:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="title" name="title" autocomplete="off" value="{{ $pageContent -> title 
}}"><br>
  @error('title') <p style="color: red">{{ $message }}</p> @enderror
  <label for="URI">URI:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="URI" name="URI" autocomplete="off" value="{{ $pageContent -> URI }}">
```

@error('URI') {{ $message }} @enderror
      Page Content:
       pageContent }}"> 
    
      @error('pageContent') {{ $message }} @enderror
      
    
    
        tinymce.init({
            selector:'#pageContent'
        })

My GitHub repository is attached below, because the question formatting for the form looks a bit screwed up...

https://github.com/xiaoheixi/wfams

Thanks for reading my question! :D

Comment: The error is "Call to a member function update() on null" means that $obj is null. It seems  $obj = \App\Page::find($URI); did not return what you were expecting

Comment: You are calling the request(), but in this function you are not using Request, `public function update($URI)` so change to `public function update(Request $request, $URI)`

Comment: Sure, I am going to change that now.

Comment: I changed, it but its still not working.

Comment: After changed which error you get?

Comment: Exactly the same error! "Call to a member function update() on null".

Comment: try instead `$request->all()` if not work, then give me the output of `dd($request->all());`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221404/discussion-between-dwarf-champion-and-sta).

Comment: why are you using the 'URI' and not the 'id' to identify the record?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using **Request**, so you need to call the **Request** in your function, For `update()` method you can use `where()` instead  :

```
public function update(Request $request)
{
    $data = $request->validate([
        'title' => 'required',
        'URI' => 'required|min:5|max:10',
        'pageContent' => 'required'
    ]);

    $obj = \App\Page::where('URI', $request->URI)
        ->update([
            'title' => $request->title, 
            'pageContent' => $request->pageContent
        ]);

    return redirect('/p');
}
```

See the official documentation here [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#updates)

Comment: he may change the 'URI' @sta, you can use route model binding

Comment: I tried to watch the YouTube video on Route Model Binding, I don't really understand, and tried everything for like 5 hours about route model binding and doesn't work.

Comment: @DwarfChampion added an answer to use as practice code

Comment: @lagbox thare are two reason. They call the request, but did not define it to the function. And the _find()_ method  by deafult search the `id` on the table,  right? They are calling the  field `URI` which is a string, so `find()` can't do anything here.

Comment: There are no update() method in find() method, directly but update() can be possible with fill() method in find(). Anyway,  I updated my answer.

Comment: also, if they actually change the `URI` for this in that form, then this will not find the record and update it since `$request->URI` will return the request input named `URI` before it would fallback to returning the route parameter named `URI`.

Answer (score 0):

i recommend that you validate the URI existence using validation rule '[exists](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-exists)':

```
  $data = request()->validate([
        'title' => 'required',
        'URI' => 'required|min:5|max:10|exists:pages,URI',
        'pageContent' => 'required'
    ]);
```

now if the URI is not existed in your pages table, laravel will return a validation error with message like 'the specified URI is not existed in table pages'

Comment: I have an issue, it says the error is now, "Undefined variable: URI".

Comment: php artisan route:list , the find your route 'page/' and make sure of the parameter name send to update method

Comment: @OMR im guessing he's not set the getRouteKeyName() to 'URI'

Answer (score 0):

i saw your github https://github.com/xiaoheixi/myFirstWebsite

sample use model bind in controller :

> ```
> Route::patch('/page/{URI}','PageController@update');
> ```

> ```
> Route::get('{URI}', 'PageController@getPage');
> ```

> ```
> public function update($URI)
> {
>     $data = request()->validate([
>         'title' => 'required',
>         'URI' => 'required|min:5|max:10',
>         'pageContent' => 'required'
>     ]);
>     $obj = \App\Page::find($URI);
>     $obj->update(request()->all());
>     return redirect('/p');
> }
> ```

change controller into :

```
use App\Page;

public function getPage(Page $URI)
{
    return view('page_view', compact('URI'));
}

public function update(Request $request, Page $URI)//match $URI to {URI}
{
    $data = $request->validate([
        'title' => 'required',
        'URI' => 'required|min:5|max:10|unique:pages,URI,'.$URI->id, //you dont want a duplicate URI when you search a page by URI
        'pageContent' => 'required'
    ]);
    
    $URI->update($request->all());
    return redirect('/p');
}
```

in blade:

```
<form action="/page/{{ $pageContent }}" method="post">
```

in model:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Page extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['title', 'URI', 'pageContent'];
    public function getRouteKeyName()
    {
        return 'URI';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error means that `find` returned `null`. Which makes sense since `find` will be trying to search the primary key field not the `URI` field.

I would not be using the `URI` as the identifier for this record. I would be using it's `id`.

```
<form action="/page/{{ $pageContent->id }}" method="post">

Route::patch('/page/{page}','PageController@update');
```

This would simplify things quite a bit. Now you can easily use Route Model binding to get this `Page` for you:

```
use App\Page;
...

public function update(Page $page)
{
    $data = request()->validate([
        'title' => 'required',
        'URI' => 'required|min:5|max:10',
        'pageContent' => 'required'
    ]);

    $page->update(request()->all());

    return redirect('/p');
}
```

This will ensure that `$page` is an existing model instance. Since that will be the case you can call `update` on it. Just make sure that `title`, `URI` and `pageContent` are "fillable".